# Computation with numbers from files

Tags: awk

I have data that consists of a file1 with two columns and a file2 with one column. I need to apply this computation

```
for (i = 1; i == NR)

{x = ($1-T1)/Fi; print (x-int(x))}
```

where $1 is a first column of file1, T1 is a first row of first column of file 1 and Fi is row i in file2.

file1

```
5     2
56    3
566   2
54    2
```

file2

```
1
2
6
8
```

The computatiou should be

```
{x = ($1(file1)-5)/1; print (x-int(x))}
--> output1
{x = ($1(file1)-5)/2; print (x-int(x))}
--> output2
{x = ($1(file1)-5)/6; print (x-int(x))}
--> output3
{x = ($1(file1)-5)/8; print (x-int(x))}
--> output4
```

Desired result are four files with a column of 4 numbers. I mean that only $1 are number that vary during the computation and the other variable are fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'FNR == NR { F[++n] = $1; next } FNR == 1 { T1 = $1 } { for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) { x = ($1 - T1)/F[i]; print x - int(x) >"output" FNR} }' file2 file1
```

This first reads the contents of `file2` (the first file given on the command line, which is the one with the single column in it) and stores it in the array `F`.

It then reads `file1` and for each of its lines computes as many numbers as there are values in the `F` array.  For each line of `file1` these computed numbers are outputted into a file with the name `output` followed by the corresponding line number in `file1`.

Results:

```
$ ls
file1   file2   output1 output2 output3 output4
$ cat output1
0
0
0
0
$ cat output2
0
0.5
0.5
0.375
$ cat output3
0
0.5
0.5
0.125
$ cat output4
0
0.5
0.166667
0.125
$ cat output5
```

---

The `awk` script with annotations:

```awk
FNR == NR {
    # This is the first file.
    # Read its data into F, and then continue.

    F[++n] = $1
    next
} 

# We are now only processing the second file.

FNR == 1 {
    # Save T1 from the first line of the second file.
    T1 = $1
} 

{
    # Loop through F and compute x for each.
    for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        x = ($1 - T1)/F[i]

        # Print to the file given by the current line number.
        print x - int(x) >"output" FNR
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much and how to do the cyklus that would use various lines from file2 and produse output file for each line of file2? I didn't ment read Fi from the line like in column 1, but fix Fi for all $1 --> output, then take second Fi --> output2

Comment: @LukášAltman I don't know what a "cyklus" is. You will have to explain further by clarifying your question. In the question, currently, you show four computations at the end. These are the ones I'm computing above.

Comment: I editted it. I am sorry it was confusing.

Comment: @LukášAltman Updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much I learned new things and please how to do this? Let's say Fi, where i = 1,2,3,4 are numbers from file2, thus F1 = 1, F2 = 2, F3 = 6, F4 = 8. There will be 4 computation in cycle with 4 outputs. In the first cycle T1 (number in first line in first column in file1 is fixed - it is always fixed) and F1 are fixed. Then T1 and F2 are fixed for computation with $1, third output is with T1 and F3 fixed and the last output is with T1 and F4 fixed.